# Can't bind to local 8632 for debugger

Tags: java, android, debugging

I am facing the error when launching the app i the emulator for the first time .emulator is from android not third party emulators

**port 8632 error**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the port is used by another process.
If you are using Windows, run the following command:

```
netstat -a -n -o
```

If you are using Linux, run the following command:

```
sudo ss -tulpn | grep :8632
```

And stop/kill the process ID that is using this port.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your port is occupied

you can run `lsof -i:8632` to check what process is run on port 8632 and kill it  `kill -9 PID`

or....restart your computer